# Factorial Formula Generalisation

Tags: factorial

How can I generalise the following formula? It seems to be linked somehow to factorial.

$$1 + N + (N-1)  N + (N-2)  (N-1)  N + (N-3)  (N-2)  (N-1)  N \dots$$

Comment: See http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+4%2C+15%2C+64%2C+325%2C+1956%2C+13699&sort=&language=english&go=Search

Comment: This is basically a sum of falling factorials

Comment: What about it do you want to generalize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{N!}{(N-n)!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $N=N!/(N-1)!$, $(N-1)N=N!/(N-2)!$ ....

Answer (score 1):

*Small addendum:* Note, the expression has only *finitely* many summands which are not equal to zero, as the terms  eventually contain a factor $$(N-N)=0$$

> We can write
>   \begin{align*}
> 1+N+(N-1)N+(N-2)(N-1)N+\cdots&=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{N!}{(N-n)!}\tag{1}\\
> &=N!\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{1}{(N-n)!}\tag{2}\\
> &=N!\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\tag{3}\\
> &=N!\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n!}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we can set the upper limit of the sum to $N-1$ since all other summands are $0$.
- In (2) we factor out $N!$ which does not depend on the summation index $n$.
- In (3) we revert the order of summation by letting $n\rightarrow N-1-n$.
- In (4) we shift the index $n$ by one to start with $n=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left[\prod_{k=0}^{j-1}(N-k)\right]
$$

In terms of the factorial, this is
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{N!}{(N-j)!}
$$